# How to enable RequiresSession Property in Subscription

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have topics and subscription already been created in production.Now I have to enable **RequiresSession** for the existing Subscription without losing the data. But it is allowing to set the property while creating.

How can I enable **RequiresSession** for a subscription either by coding or via Azure Portal without losing any data in production?

any suggestion please

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intentional. Messages that were sent previously would not have session ID set. 
You can't modify the already existing entity. You'd have to either have a different (new) subscription with `RequireSession` enabled. Or drain the existing one and re-create it.